# Firebase Messaging getToken() not resolving

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am calling messaging.getToken() but the Promise never resolves.

```
let msging

const msgTokenPromise = navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
        .then(reg => {
          if(firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
            msging = firebase.messaging()
            // msging.onTokenRefresh = msging.onTokenRefresh.bind(msging)
            msging.useServiceWorker(reg)
            return msging.requestPermission()
          } else throw "messaging not supported"
        })
        .then (() => {let prom = msging.getToken();
                      console.log("tokenProm", prom);
                      return prom
                    })
        .catch(err => console.log('permission error', err))

const msgToken$ = 
        concat( from(msgTokenPromise)
              , defer(() => Observable.create(msging.onTokenRefresh).pipe(switchMap(() => from(msging.getToken()))))
              )


msgToken$.subscribe(currToken => {console.log('currToken', currToken)}
```

I am getting the log tokeProm as a pending promise in then console but never logging the token.  Couldn't find a solution to this and can't find an error.  I'm using with rxjs.

UPDATE:  When I clear the cache and service worker and restart it now resolves.  So my question becomes:  What could cause the getToken() call to not resolve?